# Margin on child element moves parent element

Tags: css, xhtml, margin, nested

I have a `div` (**parent**) that contains another `div` (**child**). Parent is the first element in `body` with no particular CSS style. When I set

```
.child
{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The end result is that top of my child is still aligned with parent. Instead of child being shifted for 10px downwards, my parent moves 10px down.

My `DOCTYPE` is set to `XHTML Transitional`.

**What am I missing here?**

*edit 1*
My parent needs to have strictly defined dimensions because it has a background that has to be displayed under it from top to bottom (pixel perfect). So setting vertical margins on it is a **no go**.

*edit 2*
This behaviour is the same on FF, IE as well as CR.

Comment: On few browsers or only one specific one?

Comment: this behavior makes no sense what so ever. Margin is suppose to stay inside the parent. Not move the parent. Who writes these rules.

Comment: +2 for last comment. seriously this *rule* bugs me. "60% of the time it works every time" - that's margins.

Comment: I totally agree with the two last commenters. This is insane. What's interesting is that adding a 1px border to the parent makes it work right, however this means you have a border...if this is the expected behavior then this is ridiculous

Comment: Please provide more information about specification which is applied. Thank you.

Comment: This may also help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337043/when-i-try-to-shift-the-image-upwards-using-negative-margin-the-whole-container

Comment: This reminds me of the default box-sizing rule: "*We need to ship a box. The box must not be larger than 100cm. We need 10cm of padding inside the box to ensure our content doesn't break during the shipping. Let's make the box 120cm!*" What a joke.

Comment: It's due to margin collapsing. Here's another illustration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38679945/3597276

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I learn CSS just for myself now, and observe the same behaviour with margin inside parent. Now I see I understand it correctly and Im not insane ;)

Answer (score 600, accepted):

Found an alternative at [Child elements with margins within DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878997/child-elements-with-margins-within-divs) You can also add:

```
.parent { overflow: auto; }
```

or:

```
.parent { overflow: hidden; }
```

This prevents the margins to [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). Border and padding do the same.
Hence, you can also use the following to prevent a top-margin collapse:

```
.parent {
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

2021 update: if you're willing to [drop IE11 support](https://caniuse.com/flow-root) you can also use the new CSS construct `display: flow-root`. See [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) for the whole details on block formatting contexts.

---

**Update by popular request:**
The whole point of collapsing margins is handling textual content. For example:

```css
h1, h2, p, ul {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}

div { outline: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<h1>Title!</h1>
<div class="text">
  <h2>Title!</h2>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <h2>Title!</h2>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <ul>
    <li>list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Because the browser collapses margins, the text would appear as you'd expect, and the `<div>` wrapper tags don't influence the margins. Each element ensures it has spacing around it, but spacing won't be doubled. The margins of the `<h2>` and `<p>` won't add up, but slide into each other (they collapse). The same happens for the `<p>` and `<ul>` element.

Sadly, with modern designs this idea can bite you when you explicitly want a container. This is called a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) in CSS speak. The `overflow` or margin trick will give you that.

Comment: @Tom Fitton: without it, much sites would not work. This is a real essential cornerstone of the CSS standard, so you can expect it to work.

Comment: i wanna know why does this happen what good this does to anyone. What situation this 'feature' was meant to be.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer, well this has to do with text content. For example, a series of `<h2>`, `<p>`, `<ul>` won't get strange gaps or "double" margins this way.

Comment: Could you give some example. Let say i have div as background. With h1, h2 and p in it. Now i want to move h1 down a bit so it's not so near to the above edge of background div, yet not expand the h1 element itself. I'd think add top margin. Which is obvious. but when i do that, the glorious background decides to move down with it. How this is a feature. How this helps in spacing between h1,h2, and p. Help me see what you are saying.

Comment: I've added an example for you

Comment: see even with your example this doesnt make any sense to me. what good does moving the parent do for this example? i want h1 to be further from the top of my box so i add margin-top: 3em; why the heck would i want the parent to move down 3em landing the h1 right where i still dont want it to be instead of just moving the h1 down? your example does nothing to explain this concept!

Comment: @JLGriffin: you can't have it both ways. Most of the time it does what you need without ever getting noticed. Sometimes it doesn't and you need to override it. Yes that's annoying - but consider the alternative. If browsers would keep all margins inside containers, the Internet would be full of questions like "why does inserting a <div> in my text add more margin?". Now you can just do that without any side effects.

Comment: i would expect it to add in more margin. collapsing margins is by far the most annoying thing in my development career. if i put 2 divs next to each other with `margin: 5px 10px;` id expect 2 divs 5 px from the top and 20px between them not 5 px from the top and 10px between them. if i wanted 10 px between them id have specified `margin: 5px 5px;`. i honestly wish there was a root rule i could place that would stop all margin collapsing. i hate that i have to double the size of the margins on paper to get them to actually do what the heck i want on screen. and this top thing... what a disaster

Comment: plus as per your example of why does inserting a div in my text add margin, its as simple as: `.div-in-text{ margin: 0;}` and `<div class="div-in-text"></div>`

Comment: `padding-top: 0.1px;`

Comment: is it safe to set `overflow:auto` on all `div`s of html page? Does it conflicts with 3rd party plugins e.g. Google maps?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour no, because `overflow:auto` adds scrollbars whenever the content doesn't fit. It surely breaks third party. Only use it where you really have to.

Comment: This just took up half my day, Here is what I think is a good explanation https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/margins-in-css/#parent-first-last-child-element. `display: flow-root` looks like another option.

Answer (score 66):

This is normal behaviour (among browser implementations at least). Margin does not affect the child's position in relation to its parent, unless the parent has padding, in which case most browsers will then add the child's margin to the parent's padding.

To get the behaviour you want, you need:

```
.child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.parent {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Adding border to the parent will effect the child's margin too, try `.parent {border: solid 1px;}`

Comment: The margin doesn't add to the padding... it applies separately.  But the visual effect is the same.

Comment: What if you want a top-margin…? Not really a solution.

Comment: Like feeela said - this isn't really a solution if a top margin is required. vdboor's answer suits better.

Comment: There are bunch of solutions, you just need to be creative enough. Cheers. :-)

Comment: This is a great answer. And these days (at least in Firefox - haven't tested others) you don't even need to remove the child's `margin-top`. Simply setting *any* padding on the parent will let the child's margin move it relative to the parent instead.

Comment: "Margin does not affect the child's position in relation to its parent, unless the parent has padding"

Correction: *`margin-top` does not affect the child's position..., but `margin-left` does. It's so weird that `margin-top` and `margin-left` diverge in behavior like this.

See this code pen: https://codepen.io/joseville/pen/rNrKJRy

Answer (score 30):

Although all of the answers fix the issue but they come with trade-offs/adjustments/compromises like

- `floats`, You *have* to float elements
- `border-top`, This pushes the parent at least 1px downwards which should then be adjusted with introducing `-1px` margin to the parent element itself. This can create problems when parent already has `margin-top` in relative units.
- `padding-top`, same effect as using `border-top`
- `overflow: hidden`, Can't be used when parent should display overflowing content, like a drop down menu
- `overflow: auto`, Introduces scrollbars for parent element that has (intentionally) overflowing content (like shadows or tool tip's triangle)

The issue can be resolved by using CSS3 pseudo elements as follows

```
.parent::before {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  margin-top: -1px;
  height: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hLgbyax5/1/

Comment: `margin-top: -1px` seems to be unnecessary. But I like this.

Comment: Actually, both `margin-top: -1px` and `height: 0` seems unnecessary. Tested in Chrome. But best solution.

Comment: This method mostly works, but will not respect the bottom margin for the last element within the container. It is not an equal fix to overflow: hidden; for example.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo the answer can be modified to work with bottom margin of last element by using `.parent:after...`

Comment: This is most definitely the correct answer nowadays. Works flawlessly (put it on both after and before), I hope people dare to scroll past the other ones!

Answer (score 25):

add style `display:inline-block` to child element

Answer (score 15):

the parent element has not to be empty at least put `&nbsp;` before the child element.

Comment: yes, sometimes only this can help... or better put something like this: **<div style='width:0;height:0'>&nbsp;</div>**

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me

```
.parent {
padding-top: 1px;
margin-top: -1px;
}

.child {
margin-top:260px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/97fzwuxh/

Answer (score 5):

To prevent "Div parent" use margin of "div child":

In parent use these css:

- Float
- Padding
- Border
- Overflow

Answer (score 3):

### Neat CSS-only solution

Use the following code to prepend a contentless first-child to the unintentionally moving div:

```
.parent:before
{content: '';position: relative;height: 0px;width: 0px;overflow: hidden;white-space: pre;}
```

The advantage of this method is that you do not need to change the CSS of any existing element, and therefore has minimal impact on design. Next to this, the element that is added is a pseudo-element, which is *not* in the DOM-tree.

Support for pseudo-elements is wide-spread: Firefox 3+, Safari 3+, Chrome 3+, Opera 10+, and IE 8+. This will work in any modern browser (be careful with the newer `::before`, which is not supported in IE8).

### Context

If the first child of an element has a `margin-top`, the parent will adjust its position as a way of collapsing redundant margins. Why? It's just like that.

Given the following problem:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {position: relative;}
.parent {background-color: #ccc;}
.child {margin-top: 40px;}
</style>

<div class="parent"><!--This div moves 40px too-->
    <div class="child">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

You can fix it by adding a child with content, such as a simple space. But we all hate to add spaces for what is a design-only issue. Therefore, use the `white-space` property to fake content.

```
<style type="text/css">
div {position: relative;}
.parent {background-color: #ccc;}
.child {margin-top: 40px;}
.fix {position: relative;white-space: pre;height: 0px;width: 0px;overflow: hidden;}
</style>

<div class="parent"><!--This div won't move anymore-->
    <div class="fix"></div>
    <div class="child">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

Where `position: relative;` ensures correct positioning of the fix. And `white-space: pre;` makes you not having to add any content - like a white space - to the fix. And `height: 0px;width: 0px;overflow: hidden;` makes sure you'll never see the fix.

You might need to add `line-height: 0px;` or `max-height: 0px;` to ensure the height is actually zero in ancient IE browsers (I'm unsure). And optionally you could add `<!--dummy-->` to it in old IE browsers, if it does not work.

In short, you can do all this with only CSS (which removes the need to add an actual child to the HTML DOM-tree):

```
<style type="text/css">
div {position: relative;}
.parent {background-color: #ccc;}
.child {margin-top: 40px;}

.parent:before {content: '';position: relative;height: 0px;width: 0px;overflow: hidden;white-space: pre;}
</style>

<div class="parent"><!--This div won't move anymore-->
    <div class="child">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only use this solution if you are desperate, and you can't set any custom CSS to the existing elements - otherwise use the real solution: set `overflow: hidden;` for the parent.

Answer (score 3):

**Play with display of parent**

```
.parent{
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.parent{ display: flex; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I find out that, 
inside of your .css >if you set the *display property* of a div element to **inline-block** it fixes the problem. and margin will work as is expected.

Answer (score 2):

It's about [Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

> The **top** and **bottom** margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as **margin collapsing**.

There are several solutions, depending on the individual case.
One solution is to change the display mode for the child.

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also good to know. Margin collapsing is not applied on flex or gird container.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Or working with `padding` of parent instead of `margin` of childs. Changing `overflow` or `float` property could also help. Or `position` absolute. It depends on your layout.

Comment: So it's like negative margin collapsing?

Answer (score 1):

The `margin` of the elements contained within `.child` are collapsing.

```
<html>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #parent {background:#dadada;}
    #child {background:red; margin-top:17px;}
</style>
<body>
<div id="parent">

    <p>&amp;</p>

    <div id="child">
        <p>&amp;</p>    
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, `p` is receiving a `margin` from the browser default styles. Browser default `font-size` is typically 16px. By having a `margin-top` of more than 16px on `#child` you start to notice it's position move.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too but preferred to prevent negative margins hacks, so I put a

`<div class="supercontainer"></div>`

around it all which has paddings instead of margins. Of course this means more divitis but it's probably the cleanest way to do get this done properly.

Answer (score 1):

interestingly my favorite solution to this problem isn't yet mentioned here: using floats.

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent{width:100px; height:100px;}
.child{float:left; margin-top:20px; width:50px; height:50px;}
```

see it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iphol

note that in case you need dynamic height on the parent, it also has to float, so simply replace `height:100px;` by `float:left;`

Answer (score 1):

Using `top` instead of `margin-top` is another possible solution, if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution I found before I knew the correct answer was to add a **transparent border** to the parent element.

Your box will use extra pixels though...

```
.parent {
    border:1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by adding a `:before` pseudo element with `display: flex;` to the parent.

```css
.parent:before {
  content: '';
  display: flex;
}
```

Another way is to set the `display` property of the parent to `flow-root`.

```css
.parent {
  display: flow-root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The border solution is good but not the best because it increase the element total width even when being transparent

but what about *negative border width* ? not working :(

but still we can achieve it with `box-sizing property`
which forcing the border to the negative direction

```
.parent{
   border:5px solid transparent;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
.child{
   margin-top:5px; 
 }
```

Notice if you want `10px top margin` you have to add only `5px margin` because `5px border` top still affecting and this reason to prevent collapsing issue.