# Child elements with margins within DIVs

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I need two consecutive `div` elements (with backgrounds) to be touching seamlessly, one below the other. However, this layout breaks when I put a child `p` element into the bottom `div`. The margins of the `p` element force a blank gap between both `div` elements. This is strange behavior, as I am expecting the margin of the `p` to stay within the content and background area of the `div`. It renders the same way on Firefox, Chrome and IE 8.

```
<div style="background: #ccccff">Top Div</div>
<div style="background: #ffcccc"><p>Bottom Div</p></div>
```

Here's what it looks like.

[image: Image showing the top div (in blue), then a white gap, then the bottom div (in pink). The white gap should not be present.]

I could fix this by changing the margins to paddings for the `p` element, but then I would also have to do this with header elements, list elements, and any other element I want to use at the start of a `div`. That is not desirable.

Could someone enlighten me: what caveat of the box model am I missing? Is there an easy way to fix this, preferably by modifying the style of the `div`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is the [expected behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)*. There are a few ways to get around it. If you float the divs, they will contain the margins of child elements and prevent margin collapsing. Another approach is to add a border or padding to the divs.

* The margins of the div and the p "combine to form a single margin", even though they are nested, because they have adjoining margins with no padding or border between them.

Comment: Yup, that looks like collapsing borders. I still find it kind of peculiar though. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Expected behavior in browsers is all too often unexpected

Answer (score 33):

Add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to the div

Comment: Doesn't work when parent has another dropdown div, like it is in my case (

Answer (score 11):

**Solution 1**

Add overflow: hidden/auto to the containing div to prevent the margin collapsing.

**Solution 2**

Add positive padding to the containing div and equal negative margin to the inner element

**New Solution**

Add padding of 0.01px to the containing div, this will prevent the margin collapsing but won't need any negative margin on the inner element.

Comment: On Chrome 0.01px densest work for me but 0.1px does. I can see the appeal of this solution over using overflow, but has anyone tested it extensively cross browser?

Comment: For Chrome use : padding-top: 0.02px;

Answer (score 2):

Setting a positive padding, and a corresponding negative margin on the `div` element seems to fix the issue, though I know not why.

```
<div style="background: #ccccff">Top Div</div>
<div style="background: #ffcccc; padding: 1px; margin: -1px"><p>Bottom Div</p></div>
```