# HTML CSS: odd behavior that I can't understand, extra space disapperars when adding a border

Tags: html, css

css/hmtl newbie here. I've been messing with divs and I'm getting some odd behavior that I can't figure out/explain. I'm getting extra space below the 'more' link, when it should be centered on the y-axis.

This is the code:

```
#show-rec-box {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 286px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;  

}
```

but when I change it to this, the extra space disappears!

```
#show-rec-box {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 286px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec; 
    border: 1px solid #911; 
}
```

entire code w/o extra border: http://jsfiddle.net/8q3Ca/
code with extra border: http://jsfiddle.net/8q3Ca/1/ 
any ideas what's happening?? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have margin-top on `#rec-title`. It's margin collapse - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins Try use 'overflow:auto' for a parent block . Similar question [Child elements with margins within DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878997/child-elements-with-margins-within-divs)

http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/8q3Ca/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm confused however about the rec-title margin being a problem, when I remove the rec-title margins to see the effect, the problem with the extra space below 'more' is still there. Could you explain why the content of the div#show-rec-box is overflowing and would need 'overflow: hidden;'? Thanks a lot

Comment: @trying_hal9000 i added link to w3c spec and similar question - "There are a few ways to get around it. If you float the divs, they will contain the margins of child elements and prevent margin collapsing. Another approach is to add a border or padding to the divs."

Answer (score 0):

Replace #main, #show-rec-box, and #rec-wrap with the following css..
Is this something you want to achieve?

```
#main {
    border: solid 1px #ececec;
    width: 793px;
    float: left;
}


#show-rec-box {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 286px;
}

#rec-wrap {
    margin: 0px 27px 0px 28px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```