# Adding a border "pushes down" contents

Tags: html, css, border

I have a p element with a paragraph of text inside a div element. Without a border on the div element, the p element is positioned in the top-left corner, but if I add a border to the div element it "pushes down" the paragraph from the top edge (not the left edge, however).

Why does this occur?, and is there a method of preventing this?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 450px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: Pink;
}

div.first {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: Black;
}

p {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: Black;
  color: White;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <p class="one">Paragraph one text...</p>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <p class="two">Paragraph two text...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: May not be relevant to your question but it's good to know that borders can be created using only one styling command: `border: 2px solid black;`.

Comment: See [Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element).

Comment: @Luicy, thankyou for this; at the moment, when I learn new concepts, I am trying to write them out in the extended way, to try and reinforce them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE:

You can prevent this movement by adding `margin: 0;` to the style of your `p` tag. See below for an explanation of how and why this happens.

---

The reason your `p` tag gets pushed down is because of **margin collapsing** (or, rather, margins not collapsing when you set a border).

[See this page for a more in-depth explanation of how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). From that page:

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing. Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

Basically, **your margins are getting collapsed by the browser** *when you don't have a border set*, **yet they are calculated** *when you do set that border*.

---

For ways to prevent the browser from collapsing margins, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element). From that question (first part originally quoted from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878997/child-elements-with-margins-within-divs)):

> Found an alternative at Child elements with margins within DIVs You can also add:
>
> `.parent { overflow: auto; }`
>
> or:
>
> `.parent { overflow: hidden; }`
>
> This prevents the margins to collapse. Border and padding do the same. Hence, you can also use the following to prevent a top-margin collapse:
>
> `.parent {
>       padding-top: 1px;
>       margin-top: -1px;
>   }`

Comment: This is perfect. I only thought of margin collapsing in terms of siblings, not a kind-of "overlap" between parent and child. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [margin collapse](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).
The margin on the `<p>` element collapses with it's parent.

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

Note that:

> Adjoining vertical margins collapse... if and only if... no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and **no border** separate them.

---

In order to prevent margin collapse on both of your examples, you can use methods other than `border`. For example, `overflow:auto`:

> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 450px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: Pink;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

div.first {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: Black;
}

p {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: Black;
  color: White;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <p class="one">Paragraph one text...</p>
</div>
<div class="second">
  <p class="two">Paragraph two text...</p>
</div>
```

See also:
[Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).
[What You Should Know About Collapsing Margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/).