# margin-top doesn't move unless value is high

Tags: css, html, margin

Probably a very simple fix to this one, been looking at it for a little bit now and cant figure it out.. Here is my code:

```
    margin-top:10px;
    width:998px;
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:300px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image:url(../images/default/page.png);
    overflow:hidden;
```

When the margin-top is set at 10px the div doesn't move at all. If i set the margin-top to be 200px then the div doesn't move. However if i set it to say 500px then it moves down 500 as expected.

I have already tried removing the min & max heights for just a single set height however this doesn't sort the problem. Not that it should cause issues in the first place.

Can anyone see my mistake? I am sure my coding is relatively sound and don' really know how to research solving this issue.

Comment: I forget what happens specifically, but it's possible the margin is being applied to the element's parent. Try using padding on the parent instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: The problem lies with the structure and styling of the ancestors of whatever element this CSS applies to... but the specific issue is impossible to pinpoint without seeing a broader snapshot of both your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` or use `margin-bottom` on the preceeding element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolved this issue by placing the divs above this one within another container Div and applying a margin-bottom:10px to it.

Its not totally ideal because it takes a little longer to code and adds another div which i don't really want but suppose it will have to do for now until i have a little more time to read up on this issue fully.

Thanks to everyone for your help and potential solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `margin` and `float` of other elements. I don't see any problems with the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, adjacent vertical margins collapse, pending certain conditions.

So say you have 2 divs stack 1 on top of another. The top div has a margin bottom of 30px, and the bottom div has a margin top of 20px. In this situation, the margins 'collapse' into the highest value, the 30px margin bottom on the top div.

More info on this can be found [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

In your situation, i'd look at the CSS of the surrounding elements to see if changing those values would do what you want.