# A CSS absolute positioning mystery

Tags: css, html, css-position

Consider the webpage below.  The `<img>` is positioned absolutely relative to its parent, and when I load this page on Safari or Firefox, the `<img>` appears in the top-right, as expected (see first image).  However, when the border is removed from from the `<div>`, for example, by setting `border-width: 0`, the `<img>` positions itself absolutely relative to the `<p>` tag, its sibling!  See picture #2. Why is this?  What difference should the border make?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 20px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="content/en/flag.png" />
        <p>This is a test</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: absolutely relative to div]
[image: absolutely relative to p]

Comment: try to use css-reset and then check the page. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is always at the top-right. It has to do with [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Try to do it with a background color. You will see that your `div` is moving away from the top of the `body` a few pixels. If you delete `p`'s margin everything would be fine, or setting `p` as an inline element or floating it, or even setting an overflow to `auto`, `hidden` or `scroll` to the parent. Another way to fight the collapsed margin is to add a border to the container element. So you really was solving this with that border.

But image is always where it is supposed to be.

Comment: You can also set `padding-top: 1px;` to the parent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about collapsing margins.

Answer (score 0):

Its really strange indeed but let me try to explain this actually the elements are not float and you are using margin on `p` tag which the div is taking properly when it has border and failed to implement it when its removed if add float property than the div will also gain its height

add `overflow:auto;` to div it will fix the problem