# margin top to div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs which have background images and I would like to add margin to the the 2nd div but it is creating white space.

How can I add a top margin while keeping the div inside the other div?

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="logo">
    </div> 
</div>

.logo {
   background-image: url(image/logo2.png);
   height:40px;
   width:400px;
   margin-left:100px;
   display:block;
   margin-top:20px;
}

.background {
   background-image: url(image/empback.png);
   width:100%;
   height:94px;
   min-width:1345px;
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at `Mr.Alien's` answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a use of `css` `position` property here.

**Sample Code**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="logo">
    </div> 
</div>

.logo
{
    background-image: url(image/logo2.png);
    height:40px;
    width:400px;
    margin-left:100px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
}

.background
{
    background-image: url(image/empback.png);
    width:100%;
    height:94px;
    min-width:1345px;
    position:relative;
}
```

remove `margin-top:20px;` and add `position` and `top` property for `.logo`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `overflow: auto` on the parent element

```
.background{
    background: #f00;
    width:100%;
    height:94px;
    min-width:1345px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhSgZ/)

Just got a link to [share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element) which is related to this issue.

---

Also, a better approach towards this is instead of using `position: absolute;` you should use `position: relative;` with `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties, which will not only keep the element in float, it will also save you from positioning other elements in the same block.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/XhSgZ/2/)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Would love to see if this has any bad side, I usually go for relative absolute thing, but this solution works as well...

Comment: you got +1 from me, setting a position absolute to a child in not always desirable. Good catch

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, than if your parent element has multiple elements,if you set 1 to absolute, you need to set other as well or use explicit margins and paddings or floats, and anyways thanks :)

Comment: Exactly, setting overflow to `auto` does absolutely nothing bad. Actually now, thinking a bit more about it this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mr.Alien upset on your behalf for the downvote, +1 my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Just Go through the code.

By just changing `position` and `top` value we can get the result.

```
.logo{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.background{
     position: absolute;
     background-color: green;
     width: 100%;
     top: 50px;
     height: 94px;
     min-width: 1345px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about not changing position and still get desired result?

Add this line to background class:

```
.background{
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```