# Nested divs and margins not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I have a `.header` div that is at the top of my page, and a `.logo` div inside of it. I want the logo div to have a top margin so there is some space between the top borders of header and logo, but when I add `margin: 15px auto;` to `.logo`, it behaves as if I put the margin style on `.header`. Here is some sample code:

html

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    height:80px;
    background-color: #8BB;
    margin: 0;
    /*padding: 15px 0 0;*/
    /*border: 1px solid yellow;*/
}

.logo {
    height: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    background-color: #B5B;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz8vD/)

I could get the desired results by using padding on `.header` instead, but I'm just curious what's going wrong with margins in my example? What's also weird is if you uncomment the border css I have in `.header`, it will work as expected.

Tested with FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the parent (header) has : **`overflow: hidden;`**

> Elements with overflow set to anything other than visible (They do not collapse margins with their children.)

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Comment: Thanks. Why don't I have control over it without `overflow: hidden;`?

Comment: @Shredder check out the box model spec for CSS http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html that should help you understand it. Also, here's the same question you posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: @disinfor Ahh... collapsing margins. Thanks you!

Comment: @Riskbreaker I edited your question with the reason why `overflow:hidden;` on parent works, with a reference. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Of course not @Shredder Being more descriptive is all in favor to the user (Tron) :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to `.logo`:

```
display: inline-block;
```

However this will align `.logo` to the left. You can fix it by adding `text-align: center;` to the `.header`

Comment: I'm not so much interested on forcing the margins to work, but why it's not working as it is.

Comment: Then probably Riskbreaker's solution will help you better.