# Removing a random blank space caused by CSS

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm creating a theme for Tumblr and locally everything works fine. Yet when I paste the code into the Tumblr editor and preview it on the site a blank space appears on the top of the page. I've looked through the css and cannot figure out why it's appearing. Any ideas I've tried everything.

Tumblr address is http://storyline-expose.tumblr.com password for it is WIP

Screenshot of the problem:
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Looks like you need some password to see the site.

Comment: The password is WIP, I posted it above. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @CarlosPerez: Please add a relevant screenshot so this question retains value for future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `margin-top:0` to `.blogTitle`

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes with the `<h1 class = "blogTitle">` and is well described here:

[Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

Another solution (besides Zach's) is to set overflow of the parent element to 0:

```
.headCoverWrapper { overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: You'd apply `overflow:auto` to the parent, `headCoverText`, not the element itself

Comment: Apparently is not the direct parent, after some tests, it should be on `.headCoverWrapper`. Changed in the answer.