# CSS margin-top of <h1> affects parent's margin

Tags: css, margin

I have look for a while now on this problem and have not found a straight answer.
When adding a margin top to an element, in my case it happens mostly with headings. In many occasions the margin-top is shared with the parent.

**HTML**

```
  <div>
      <h1>My title</h1>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  padding:20px;
}

h1{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

The result of the previous code will also add a margin-top to the div, as if we had the following:

```
div{
  padding:20px;
  margin-top:20px; /*this one is implemented by the browser, not written on the code*/
}
```

A way to solve this is by adding **`overflow:auto`** to the parent, in this case the div css has:

```
div{
  padding:20px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Although the previous example solves the problem, it is not clear to me **WHY???**.
This has something to do with **"collapsing margins"**, where apparently a margin is combined with the parent's margin. But **why????**

How do we know when a parent will collapse the margin of the child and when not, what is the purpose of this property of the blocks, or is it a bug?

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/q2Vd9/) of the problem.

And Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8bHL/) of the solution

Thanks.

Comment: I'll be interested in the answer to this one.  I have also observed this behavior and it really bugs me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: Hi @AndréFigueiredo, thanks for the link, but I don't see an explanation of why we have this behavior. I know how to solve it but it is not clear to me why. Thanks

Comment: This is why I like to do, `position: relative; top: size goes here;`. You don't need to worry about the funky way `margin` acts. (That may just be me but, I never liked using `margin`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers, @gaurav5430 posted a link with a very precise definition that I would like to summarize into this answer. As of why they decided that this elements should behave like this it is still unclear for me; but at least we were able to find a rule that applies to collapsing margins:

*"In simple terms, this definition indicates that when the vertical margins of two elements are touching, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero*

Basically in our example on the original question, the biggest margin-top is the one of the `<h1>` therefore taken and applied to the parent `<div>`.

This rule is cancelled for:

- Floated elements
- Absolutely positioned elements
- Inline-block elements
- Elements with overflow set to anything other than visible (They do not collapse margins with their children.)
- Cleared elements (They do not collapse their top margins with their parent block’s bottom margin.)
- The root element

That is the reason why `overflow:hidden` solved the issue.

Thanks  @gaurav5430; here is the reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Also thanks to @Adrift that posted very good resources, although I found @gaurav5430's answer more straight forward and easier to understand.

Answer (score 7):

If element is the first child, it will add the margin-top to the parent element, collapsing with the margin-top of parent element.

The **why** sometimes margin does not collapse is clearly said in [W3 collapsing-margins section](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins).

I recommend using padding-top or this workaround: [Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element), since `overflow: hidden` can add collateral damage.

see this example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZjUa/)

HTML:

```
<div id="outside">
    <div id="div1">
        <h1>margin in parent</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">&nbsp;
        <h1>margin inside</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outside {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: #66d;
}
#div1 h1 {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: #6d6;
}
#div2 h1 {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why.  Please actually read the question.

Comment: I don't understand the comment "This doesn't explain why". The first sentence was the most helpful thing I read on this page.

Comment: @TylerCollier IMO the question is bad formulated (specially the title), the OP's real question is why in some cases the margin does not collapse. It's a rule in the CSS spec. "Then why it's a rule in spec?" It's due the actual objective of margin, that is not "strictly" move element X pixels. Do what.. I guess people don't like to read specifications of languages they are using..

Answer (score 1):

here is a nice article, with a slight explanation

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

find this on the above link...

> Collapsing Margins Between Parent and Child Elements
>
> So far, we’ve only addressed the collapsing effect on adjacent
>   elements, but the same process holds true for parents and children
>   whose margins touch. By “touch,” we mean the places at which no
>   padding, borders, or content exist between the adjacent margins. In
>   the following example, a parent element has a child element on which a
>   top margin is set:
>
> h1 {   margin: 0;   background: #cff; } div {   margin: 40px 0 25px 0;
>   background: #cfc; } p {   margin: 20px 0 0 0;   background: #cf9; } In
>   the style sheet above, you can see that a top margin value is declared
>   for the p element, and in the code excerpt below, you can see that the
>   p element is a child of the div element:
>
> ## Heading Content
>
> Paragraph content
>
> The
>   result of this code is illustrated in Figure 2.
>
> Figure 2. Collapsing margins on a child paragraphAn illustration of
>   collapsing margins between a h1 element and
>             a div element with a child p element. There's a 40 pixel vertical
>             gap between the h1 element and the paragraph content. You may have expected that the paragraph would be located 60px from the
>   heading, since the div element has a margin-top of 40px and there is a
>   further 20px margin-top on the p element. You may also have expected
>   that 20px of the background color of the div element would show above
>   the paragraph. This does not happen because, as you can see in Figure
>   2, the margins collapse together to form one margin. Only the largest
>   margin applies (as in the case of adjoining blocks), as we’ve already
>   seen.
>
> In fact we would get the same result if our div element had no top
>   margin and the p element had a 40px margin-top. The 40px margin-top on
>   the p element effectively becomes the top margin of the div element,
>   and pushes the div down the page by 40px, leaving the p element
>   nesting snugly at the top. No background would be visible on the div
>   element above the paragraph. ...

Answer (score 0):

solving the problem with overflow:auto; ain't be good, have you tried to give an ID or CLASS to your div and then do this in ur CSS

```
#divID{
padding:auto;
}

#divID h1{
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

never use overflow cuz it may cause you more problems if you add a SELECT inside ur DIV, Good luck

There are three different ways in CSS you can dictate which elements you want to style. Each way is useful for a specific set of purposes, but by using all three together, you can really harness the cascading power of style sheets. The three methods of describing objects on a page are by their tag name, their ID, or their class.

Comment: While this might fix the problem, the question is more of _why_ does it act like that.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a border to the parent div solve the problem, I use that if i don't want a visible border, it's works well

```
div.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border:  0.01px solid transparent;
}
h1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Changing the scrolling behaviour or borders or anything else of the parent DIV is IMHO, not a good solution, as these effects could be needed for something else in your page design!

The **easiest and "not-affecting-other-elemts" method** is just changing the block type of the H-element to "inline-block" and applying a width of 100% (= expands over the entire parent width like "normal" H-blocks do). Now you may apply to this H-element whatever you want like margin, padding, line height, height etc. and the parent DIV takes no notice! - that's it!