# CSS Layout - White space when NOT using any padding

Tags: css, liquid-layout

First and foremost, I am asking this question for learning purposes and to understand CSS better. Secondly, I am using this normalize version:

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

My question is this. When I set the padding to 0 on my header element, I get a white border at the top of my layout:

[Not Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ammajmta/1/)

But, when I set ANY padding amount on my header, it does work:

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ammajmta/)

Anyone can tell me why this is?

```css
html,
body {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
body {
  font-family: verdana;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
section {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background-color: green;
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.1.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>Menu</nav>
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <section>Content</section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: The white space is because of the margin from the `h1`. You really should try to recreate your issue here, because this question will be useless to people in the future if your website is down or the issue is no longer present on there.

Comment: I know, and I will think of a way to do so using jsfiddle or something else. Thanks btw! :)

Comment: Added jsfiddle links without using the normalize in them so the issue could be reproduced.

Comment: If you open the snippet in full page mode, you can see the issue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have an h1 in your header which margin does not collapse and affects its parent's margin.

To solve this you can add `overflow: auto;` to your parent element, in this case in your `<header>` tag.

---

**MORE INFO:**

[CSS margin-top of  affects parent's margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689575/css-margin-top-of-h1-affects-parents-margin)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)