# Layout Issue in CSS (Border)

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with regards to border property in CSS. When I put border-top inside the banner id it will move or stick to the upper block element (header) but if I remove it it will have an annoying gap between header and section. I don't know what is the issue. Please help. :(

HTML

```
    <header>   
    </header>
    <section id="banner">
            <h1>Test</h1>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family:Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}

header {
    background:#333333;
    color:#ffffff;
    height:80px;
    border-bottom:red 5px solid;
}

header nav {
    float:right;
}

/*issue is here*/
#banner {
    height:500px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-top:red 5px solid;/*remove this line and see*/
    border-bottom:red 5px solid;
    background-color:green;
}

#banner h1 {
    font-size:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `margin-top` for your `h1` element inside the `#banner`.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eteLyo9y/).

For some reasons, the `block` level element, will take the `margin-top` for the first `block` element which is inside, and by setting a `border` it is removed. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689575/css-margin-top-of-h1-affects-parents-margin).

Answer (score 1):

The 'gap' is there because your `h1` got a default 50px `margin-top` (well, on a fiddle it's like that).

Just remove it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS Reset https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ first to fix multi-browser compatibility.

`html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe etc.`

Example On: jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wtqfp1vw/