# downsize width and margin-top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Responsive website with a red (left) column and a blue (right) column. The red column has a black element with `margin-top:30px`

When the website is resized and the blue column jumps down under the red column, the red column "inherits" the `margin-top`.. How can this this be avoid?

http://www.bluemachines.dk/_bootstrap/downsize/

Comment: apply `display: inline-block;` to black element (.logo)

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

Comment: @mary, create answer

Answer (score 1):

It is due to **media query** used in [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)!

You need to learn media queries for that or if you don't need media queries! Don't use classes of Bootstrap in navigation!

**Put this into @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) and it works perfectly.**

```
.nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse {
    overflow: visible;
}   
.navbar .btn-navbar {
    display: none;
}
```

or

> You can also stop the navbar from stacking by changing the
>   @grid-float-breakpoint variable to 1px

or

Media queries works on browser width for mobile devices u can also specify your style in media query css

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```

Here is link for [disabling media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
              Your Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
              Your Content
    </div>
```

Give classes for all the screen size, the problem solves!!!!