# margin-top affects inner and out elements but margin- left is not affection .why?

Tags: html, css

If I add `margin-top: 50px;` to `#box` then `#container` is also getting `margin-top`, but If I add `#margin-left: 50px` to `#box` then why isn't `#container` getting `margin-left`?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahmud786/rapvL6q8/)

#### HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="box">box</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by adding `possition:fixed` to the container like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rapvL6q8/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Please add for #box float:left. Update your css with

```
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left:25px;
    float : left;

}
```

hope this will help

Comment: Can I solve this using position : absolute or relative

Comment: Is this happening for margin collap ?

Comment: If you are trying to use position. Then give position:relative; for #container and position:absolute; for #box

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the crazy world of collapsing margins.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

You could add a transparent border on the outer div, use padding, or float the inner div with a clearfix on the outer div.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Margin Collapse works. Here are the details from W3C:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Quoted from the W3C article, "Horizontal margins never collapse."

Also from W3C, there are several ways vertical margins that touch collapse including:

1. If "no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate
   them"
2. both elements belong to adjacent box edges, "top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow
   child"

A good way to prevent this is to assign the 30px top *margin* to the parent, and also assign 10px top *padding* to the parent. This moves the parent down by 30px and also moves the child down by 10px.

Please see this similar question for more info: [Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

```
#container {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding-top:10px;
    }
    #box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: orange;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using padding in #container instead of margin in #box or use them both like this:

```
#container
{
   padding-top: 1px;
   padding-left: 1px;
}
#box
{
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rapvL6q8/7/)