# Kendo UI & AngularJS Notification CSS works incorrectly

Tags: css, angularjs, kendo-ui

If you look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kWaQevKFKQhCD7ouurpV?p=preview) and click on the "Show Notification" button you'll see that even though the background is black (background-color: #000000;) there's some gray color on top. What's wrong with this CSS/template?

the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span kendo-notification="notif" k-options="opt" style="display:none;"></span>
    <button ng-click="showNotif()">Show Notification</button>
</body>
```

the JS:

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.opt = { position: {
                 top: 30,
                 right: 30
            },
          templates: [{
            type: "growl",
            template: "<div class='growl'><h1>#= title #</h1><p>#= message #</p></div>"
            }]
        };

   $scope.showNotif = function() {
         $scope.notif.show({
            title: "This is the title",
            message: "and this is the message"
        }, "growl");
    };
}
```

the CSS:

```
.growl {
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
border: 0;
height:80px;
width:300px;
font-family: Arial;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by applying an `overflow: hidden` attribute to your `.growl` style:

```
.growl {
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
border: 0;
height:80px;
width:300px;
font-family: Arial;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Angular or Kendo.

change the CSS to this:

```
.growl {
   ...
   padding-top:10px;
}
.growl h1 {
   margin-top:0;
}
```

The full answer is already here : [Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

Comment: Paul, your answer also works, however Jon's is simpler to implement. Thanks.