# How margin works for a div with background inside element with background?

Tags: html, css

You can watch the problem here at jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Askerov/xz4t4bce/

The thing is i want to move the inside element, but i do not want parent element to move with it? Can anybody explain how it works? And how do i move such element?

```
.aa{
background:#ccc;
width:600px;
height:300px; } 
.bbb{
background:#333;
width:150px;
height:50px;
margin-top:40px;}

<div class='aa'>
<div class='bbb'>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a variety of options. Add `overflow:hidden` to the parent, or `float-left` or add an invisible 1px top border.

Comment: Insivible border worked, but what the...Could you explain how and why that happens ?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). Just add `overflow:auto;` to the parent div to restore the behavior you seek

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xz4t4bce/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS add the position of the elements, once you do that, it will allow you to move it, see here:

```
.aa{
    background:#ccc;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}

.bbb{
    background:#333;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    top:40px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/xz4t4bce/3/)