# Mysterious padding between <body> and first <div> which disappears on adding a border to the <div>

Tags: html, css, header

Please see this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/a506r2gh/

There is a weird padding appearing between body and "header" division. And it goes away if I add a border to the "header" div.
Margin collapse and body margin do not seem to be the problem here.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the html

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#"><div class="photo"></div></a>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the css

```
body {
    margin:0; padding:0; background: #999;
}
.header {
    background-color: #422;
    /* border: solid 1px red; */ /* problem goes away if I add border to header */
}
.header .photo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background: #660;
    margin:50px auto;
}
.footer {
    height:50px;
    background: #303;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: `.header .photo` has margin-top: 50px hence the gap. Give overflow: auto to .header

Comment: Thanks @anpsmn. That works. Why does the padding go away when I add that border on the div?

Comment: The padding is infact the margin on .photo that collapses with #header and renders outside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.photo` element inside your header has a top and bottom margin of 50px, which is affecting the parent.

To prevent this, add `overflow: auto` to the `.header`.

There are also [several other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element) that you can solve this.

I can't speak to *why* this happens, but here's a quote from MDN about the behavior:

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Comment: Oh... I see from the MDN quote, why adding the border affects this! Brilliant :) Thank you.