# Why a child element with a top margin doesn't stretch the parent container

Tags: css

Given a div with a child element that have a top margin, why the margin is not inside the parent div but outside ?

HTML

```
<div><h1>Titre<h1></div>
```

CSS

```
h1 { margin: 20px; }
div { background-color: #DDD; }
```

cf http://jsfiddle.net/adt515ww/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Margin on child element moves parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's due to [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). To fix it add overflow:auto to your div:

```
div {
    background-color:#DDD;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/adt515ww/1/)**