# HTML Align DIV Children Horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am very new in HTML and CSS development. I wanted all children in my div parent align horizontally

My HTML :

```
<div class="parent">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h1>World</h1>
</div>
```

I tried using `inline-block` on `.parent`  like the others suggested but still the output is :

```
Hello
World
```

instead

```
Hello World
```

any ideas?

Comment: Use inline-block for children h1 instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `display: inline;` this will make each tag render like it is "inline with each other".

```
.parent h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

You could also float the tags, but I would avoid doing that as it would break the flow of text if you were to add any other tags within the `.parent` container.

[Example JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tqb7yb6/1/)

Comment: Will this arrange "all children" horizontally or only `h1` elements?

Answer (score 4):

Consider looking at `float:left`.

```css
.parent h1 {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>World</h1>
</div>
```

Or even `display:inline`

```css
.parent h1{
  display:inline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1>World</h1>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that using `float` is not recommended here because if you add a new element to the `.parent` div it will appear next to the `h1` elements because those are floating left. +1 to @MathiasaurusRex for pointing that out.

Comment: I would be careful using floats in this context, because if you were to put any other tags within parent, the two classes would float left.
http://jsfiddle.net/1tqb7yb6/

Comment: Yeah I remembered display was a possibility too, and a much better one at that. I edited my post to be more accurate. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is as follows:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>World</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice. Is it possible to also specify children margin on parent element?

Comment: @Pawcio This is maybe what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to align the div, but need to align the h1's:
In your CSS code add:

`h1 {
    display: inline;
}`

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/opqkoawf/1/)

Answer (score -2):

One thing to note here is your choice of tags h1 for children is wrong, headers inserts an empty line before and after the header. As your motive is only to show some text header tag is not the right tag of choice.

Comment: Header tags generally are styled with generous margins by default, but they certainly do not insert blank lines.