# Margin on child and border on parent

Tags: css, border, margin

I have box with a child div. The child has a margin. If I set a border on the parent (`div.box`) the height of the element changes as shown in the following image. Where is the trick?

[image: Border on parent and margin on child]

```css
.box {
  background: #0F3;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.box-border {
  background: #0F3;
}
.text {
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="box-border">
  <div class="text">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean wierd view? May be this will help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337043/when-i-try-to-shift-the-image-upwards-using-negative-margin-the-whole-container/35337103#35337103

Comment: maybe you have to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: did you see printscreen?...once box have border...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is called **collapsing margins**.

> **Parent and first/last child**
>   If there is **no border**, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. **The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent**.
>   [*source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) emphasis mine*]

If you want to prevent the collapsing margins on the element without the border, you can see other ways here : [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing).

- float the parent
- change the parent display property to inline-block or `position:absolute;`
- set the overflow of the parent to `hidden`
- ...

**Example**  with `overflow:hidden;`:

```css
.box {
  background: #0F3;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.box-border {
  background: #0F3;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.text {
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="box-border">
  <div class="text">Content</div>
</div>
```