# Top margin is not kept within the block element

Tags: html, css

I'm reading through "HTML and CSS Design and Build Websites", one of the examples in Chapter 17 is this:

http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-17/example.html

I'm following through the HTML/CSS in the book and it mostly makes sense. What I can't understand is a little nitpick though: using the developer tools from chrome and looking at "Contact" at the bottom right, the 10px margin-top value is shown as going outside the containing section block (of class="contact details"). Why is the top margin of the Contact heading not kept *within* the section block? Or rather, why is the section block not extended to keep all the content of the heading within? A minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="example.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside>
            <section class="contact-details">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
            </section>
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
section, aside {
    display: block;
}

aside {
    width: 230px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

aside h2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: #fe6582;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
}
```

I find that if I place a border around `section` then the problem is resolved (section contains all of the heading, including its margin). Is this a HTML trait or a problem with the developer tools of chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The margin issue is actually a specified behavior.

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) more about the margin collapsing.

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337043/when-i-try-to-shift-the-image-upwards-using-negative-margin-the-whole-container) stackoverflow for a better explanation.