# Lift inner div out of its parent with negative margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to lift an inner div outside of its parent with the negative margin.

Supposing the following structure:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grand-parent {
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 background: pink;
}


.parent {
  height: 150px;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
}



.required {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <p>Neighboring parent </p>
  </div>
  <div class="parent grey">

      <div class="child required">
        <h1>
          Required Heading
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="child last">
        <h2>
          Other Heading
        </h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to lift the "Required heading" as well as all the consequent tags up, outside the parent element by applying the negative margin, so that the parent's background/margins are not affected. I am able to achieve this behavior when there is another child element coming before the "Required heading", like that:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grand-parent {
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 background: pink;
}


.parent {
  height: 150px;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
}

.first {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}


.required {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <p>Neighboring parent </p>
  </div>
  <div class="parent grey">
    <div class="child first">With another child</div>
      <div class="child required">
        <h1>
          Required Heading
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="child last">
        <h2>
          Other Heading
        </h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But without the "first child" the "Required header" actually lifts the parent fully, like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grand-parent {
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 background: pink;
}


.parent {
  height: 150px;
}

.grey {
  background-color: grey;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
}

.first {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}


.required {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: -120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <p>Neighboring parent </p>
  </div>
  <div class="parent grey">
<!--     <div class="child first">With another child</div> -->
      <div class="child required">
        <h1>
          Required Heading
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="child last">
        <h2>
          Other Heading
        </h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can this be achieved without introducing another element?

Comment: padding-top: 1px; on .grey element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I try to shift the image upwards using negative margin the whole container is moved upwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337043/when-i-try-to-shift-the-image-upwards-using-negative-margin-the-whole-container). Also see [Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element) and [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Comment: Might also work if `overflow:visible` on .parent

Comment: padding-top: 1px worked, thanks @TemaniAfif! 
also, @showdev thanks for finding the similar question, it definitely answers why that happens