# Why is child container affecting parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have created [this](https://codepen.io/Selrond/pen/vGePvd/) simple tribute page, with fixed background image. 
I wanted to offset the container with the text content (I created a class just for it: `.main-content`) a bit down with a `margin-top: 130px`, so it's not glued to the very top of the page.

```
<body>   <!-- applied background-image here -->
  <div class="darken">   <!-- dark overlay on the background image -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container main-content">    <!-- .main-content - has margin-top: 130px; applied -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">    <!-- Bootstrap centering -->
            <h1 class="display-1">St. Pope John Paul II</h1>   <!-- just another text below... -->
            <h2 class="display-4">Pope of the family</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-....... <!-- rest of the text -->
```

However - a strange thing happened - the

```
.main-content {
margin-top: 130px;
}
```

margin seems to affect the body (according to Chrome DevTools...) **thus eventually affecting (applying the `margin-top` to) the div with `.darken` class!**

I want to achieve two things:

1. Having my text offset from the top of the page
2. Having `.darken` class applied to the full viewport

**How can I achieve this?**

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/Selrond/pen/vGePvd/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Margin on child element moves parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Instead of margin use padding.

```
.main-content {
    padding-top: 130px;
}
```

Comment: @Aziz thank you! I totally forgot about them... -_- Could you tell me which two elements were collapsing their margins this time?

Comment: The margin collapsed with all of `.main-content` parents up to the `body` tag because, according to the [CSS2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins): "*no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them*".

Comment: @Aziz that seems logical, thanks for clarification, but one thing seems ilogical - why it moved the body? does that mean that when child has bigger margin that parent, the margin "shifts" from child to parent?

Comment: yes, it would be as if you applied the margin to the parent. You could break this by adding `overflow: auto` to the parent or use paddings for spacing internal elements and keep margins for adding space to the outer side of an element.

Comment: My mistake, it works on the top parent excluding body/html, in your case that would be `.darken`.

Comment: @Aziz thanks! One last question - why excluding body/html? O:) 
Thank you! You helped me a lot today

Comment: According to the spec: "*Margins of the root element's box do not collapse.*" that might be why.