# Why do static elements move?

Tags: html, css, css-position

If  static positioned elements are not affected by the top, bottom, left, and right properties, why does the box move along with the container when I change the margin-top value of the box element?

I have kept my code at: https://jsfiddle.net/b9rtwkq7/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-top: 00px;
}

.box
{
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: 100px;

}
```

Comment: @nicael: isn't static default positioning?

Comment: Huh, my bad.... I was focusing on the wrong things.

Comment: Can you plz elaborate?

Comment: Margin-top != Top...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: @seahorsepip: I thought it is for every *-top properties.

Comment: @InQusitive, no position static makes an element only ignore top, bottom, left and right not margins. Besides that it also prevents absolute child elements to be positioned relative to it's position.

Comment: Changed my answer to better code that does not affect the .container or .box in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margins are collapsed in the jsfiddle you posted: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Add overflow: auto/hidden to .container or use the following css  which I've added in a class called .no-collapse myself:

```
.no-collapse:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: I need to learn what is a collpased margin. I am a beginner in css.

Comment: It's something I even have issues with every now and then >.>, Just updated my answer above to code I just found out after testing in jsfiddle thay does not require any changes to .container or .box

Comment: Edit: seems using before still moves .container

Comment: Edit: updated code

Comment: Some links to master css?

Comment: @InQusitive didn't really have a master css with snippets like this, I just started to make one(less css): https://jsfiddle.net/seahorsepip/7kucaqkh/

Comment: sorry, master as verb.

Comment: @InQusitive, check css-tricks and codrops.