# margin of an element

Tags: html, css, margin

I have this simple html and css

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#ctr{
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;

}

#ctr > .box{
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "ctr">
  <div class = "box">
    <div class="something1"></div>
    <div class="something2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add margin-top to the white box (box class) inside the red div(ctr id), but the whole red div is getting the margin and not just the white div.

here's a jsfiddle of the example.
https://jsfiddle.net/6tvrwxhg/

Comment: You have added a top margin of 10px, and that's moved `.box` down from the top of the viewport 10px... I don't know what your expectation is.

Comment: try just to add position:absolute; to the .box class it will add the margin to the white box and the red one stay as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` (or `hidden`) to the parent (`#ctr`)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#ctr {
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

#ctr > .box{
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ctr">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="something1"></div>
    <div class="something2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

more info in a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939980/863110)

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: can you explain why it works with overflow and not as i wrote it?

Answer (score 1):

That is **Parent/First child** margin collapsing, and that happens if there is no border, padding, inline content or clearance to separate parent and child. So you can add `border-top` on parent

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#ctr {
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#ctr > .box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ctr">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="something1"></div>
    <div class="something2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can add padding to parent element or use `overflow: hidden`

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#ctr {
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden
}
#ctr > .box {
  background-color: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ctr">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="something1"></div>
    <div class="something2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about this at [`Mastering margin collapsing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)