# vertical align with float and margin

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

If I remove `margin:25px;` or set `margin-top:25px;` from `.input-box, .element-box` the elements do not align vertically. And it only affects the spanned element and not the floated. Can some explain why this happens?

```css
button.j2,
input[type=text].j2,
input[type=password].j2,
input[type=submit].j2 {
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-float-left {
  float: left;
}

.flex-float-right {
  float: right;
}

.flex-span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-box,
.element-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#search,
#name,
#email,
#phone,
#address {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#email-box {
  width: 50%;
}

#notes-box {
  clear: both;
}

#create {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="element-box flex-float-right">
    <button class="j2 round tomato-brush chalk-stroke" id="create">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box flex-span" id="search-box">
    <input class="j2 round-ends" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with margin collapse between parent and child.
The margin on `div.input-box` collapses with `div.block`.

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing. Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.
>
> **Parent and first/last child**
> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block; or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

See [Mastering margin collapsing @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

Here's a diagram to help demonstrate.
Notice how the margins for `.input-box` go outside of `.block`.

[image]

---

One solution is to assign an `overflow` value other than the default `visible` to the parent element:

```css
.block {
  overflow: auto;
}

button.j2,
input[type=text].j2,
input[type=password].j2,
input[type=submit].j2 {
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-float-left {
  float: left;
}

.flex-float-right {
  float: right;
}

.flex-span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-box,
.element-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#search,
#name,
#email,
#phone,
#address {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#email-box {
  width: 50%;
}

#notes-box {
  clear: both;
}

#create {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="element-box flex-float-right">
    <button class="j2 round tomato-brush chalk-stroke" id="create">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box flex-span" id="search-box">
    <input class="j2 round-ends" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Other solutions include:

**`padding`**

```css
.block {
  padding: 0.1px;
}

button.j2,
input[type=text].j2,
input[type=password].j2,
input[type=submit].j2 {
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-float-left {
  float: left;
}

.flex-float-right {
  float: right;
}

.flex-span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-box,
.element-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#search,
#name,
#email,
#phone,
#address {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#email-box {
  width: 50%;
}

#notes-box {
  clear: both;
}

#create {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="element-box flex-float-right">
    <button class="j2 round tomato-brush chalk-stroke" id="create">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box flex-span" id="search-box">
    <input class="j2 round-ends" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

**`border`**

```css
.block {
  border: 0.1px solid transparent;
}

button.j2,
input[type=text].j2,
input[type=password].j2,
input[type=submit].j2 {
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-float-left {
  float: left;
}

.flex-float-right {
  float: right;
}

.flex-span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-box,
.element-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#search,
#name,
#email,
#phone,
#address {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#email-box {
  width: 50%;
}

#notes-box {
  clear: both;
}

#create {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="element-box flex-float-right">
    <button class="j2 round tomato-brush chalk-stroke" id="create">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box flex-span" id="search-box">
    <input class="j2 round-ends" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

**`display:inline-block`**

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

button.j2,
input[type=text].j2,
input[type=password].j2,
input[type=submit].j2 {
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-float-left {
  float: left;
}

.flex-float-right {
  float: right;
}

.flex-span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-box,
.element-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#search,
#name,
#email,
#phone,
#address {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#email-box {
  width: 50%;
}

#notes-box {
  clear: both;
}

#create {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="element-box flex-float-right">
    <button class="j2 round tomato-brush chalk-stroke" id="create">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-box flex-span" id="search-box">
    <input class="j2 round-ends" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

For reference, also see:
[How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)
[Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

[What You Should Know About Collapsing Margins @ CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.block{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
button.j2,
input[type=text].j2,
input[type=password].j2,
input[type=submit].j2 {
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-float-left {
  float: left;
}

.flex-float-right {
  float: right;
}

.flex-span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-box,
.element-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
}

#search,
#name,
#email,
#phone,
#address {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#email-box {
  width: 50%;
}

#notes-box {
  clear: both;
}

#create {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="input-box flex-span" id="search-box">
    <input class="j2 round-ends" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
  </div>
  <div class="element-box flex-float-right">
    <button class="j2 round tomato-brush chalk-stroke" id="create">&plus;</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```