# Paragraph margins goes out of div

Tags: html, css, margins

I had always this problem when a paragraph is nested inside a `div`. The default margins of paragraph goes upper than the div and pushes the parent div down. You can inspect the The white space between divs which caused by paragraph. I don't want to eliminate the margins of paragraph but I want the margins to place inside the parent div.

```css
#div1{
background:#00ff00;
}

#div2{
background:#eeeeee;
}

p{
background:#ff8800;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Top div with unwanted space below</div>
<div id="div2">
<p>The margins of this paragraph pushes the parent div downward</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It’s called “collapsing margins”, go read up on it …

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: Ok. So should I set `overflow:auto` on all divs when I have dynamic contents? @SebastianBrosch