# Margin top causes parent div to fall

Tags: html, css, margin

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">Test</div>
</div>
```

In this simple example, `d1` is the parent element of `d2`. But `d2` causes both itself and `d1` to have a `margin-top` of `20px`. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: Your code working perfectly fine. try adding some content in d1 and you will see. right now you don't have anything so its not showing and d2 leaving margin-top.

Comment: This is the default behaviour. Similar questions asked here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Answer (score -2):

Its simple logic that, when you are using parent div and child div, then parent div will be overwrite by child div style because parent will check all inside style and give you output.

**Example:** 
if you use `margin-top: 20px;` in both d1 & d2, it will give you output from top 40px.