# Why does adding border increase box size by more than 2 px?

Tags: html, css

My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Day 01</title>

    <style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background: #23424a;
  color: white;

  margin: 0 auto;

  text-align: center;
}

.intro-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-content">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod unde rerum, deleniti ea obcaecati sint hic
                odit dicta tenetur qui ut dolorum provident sit, atque, reprehenderit nulla voluptate! Officiis,
                consectetur?</p>
            <p>Iste ipsa enim delectus porro, ullam repellendus maiores quis rem debitis cum, necessitatibus architecto
                dolor? Velit, ad quaerat blanditiis veritatis expedita totam vel voluptatem officiis officia ab modi
                voluptatibus obcaecati.</p>
            <p>Accusantium minima iusto nobis fuga hic explicabo unde illum, perferendis et animi aperiam quaerat, eaque
                deleniti alias blanditiis exercitationem commodi repudiandae ullam consequatur incidunt reiciendis
                repellat officia laboriosam. Esse, modi.</p>
            <p>Expedita cupiditate iure odit, delectus placeat optio magnam assumenda mollitia aspernatur at saepe nisi
                commodi natus excepturi voluptate. Recusandae nisi dolorem, necessitatibus optio aliquam repellat.
                Adipisci, incidunt. Consequuntur, natus nulla.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When Div intro-content's border is set to 1px, intro-content box is of size 1594x238. But when I remove the border, it size is 1594x200 instead f 1594x236. Why is it so? Screenshots are below.

Screenshot with border
[image]

Screenshot with no border
[image]

Comment: Looks like it's the same width. With a 1px border it adds 1px to *both* sides (2px). To keep the box the same size, the "inner" box is reduced by 2 because of the 2px border.

Comment: What about height? Why does height change, that too dramatically

Answer (score -2):

If the element is the first child it will add the margin-top to the parent element, collapsing with the margin-top of the parent element. Check [Collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins) article for more information.

The question was already answered in [Margin on child element moves parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element)

As described there, you can just add the following css rules

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```