# why div margin not calculated towards direct parent

Tags: html, css, margin

I am working on exercising basic CSS. I want the webpage's header layout looks like this:
[wide top margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlM1B.png).

My html:

```html
    <div class="header">
.
.
.
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="page-inside">
            <div class="row-apps">
                <div class="row-apps-item">
                    <img src="02.jpg" class="row-apps-img">
                    Kurikulum
                </div>
                <div class="row-apps-item">
                    <img src="03.jpg" class="row-apps-img">
                    Status Mahasiswa
.
.
.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.page {
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:rgb(31, 31, 31);
}

.page-inside {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.row-apps {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row-apps-item {
    color: rgb(57, 57, 207);
    width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

I intend to make `.page-inside` have distance 30px towards the content main container `.page` (with black background preserved). So I add that margin, but I got 30px from `.page-inside` towards `.header` instead. It looks like this: [broken top margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93X1a.png). I already ensured (by Chrome dev tools) the white space is due to `.page-inside`, not `header` or `.page`.

I know I can just add padding to either `.page-inside` or `.row-items` but I believe adding that margin should work too. What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) creates space around an element. When you add `margin: 30px auto` to the `.page-inside` container your adding 30px of top and bottom "space" around the `.page-inside` containers content. This is what's causing the 30px of white space in between `.page` and the nav bar. The reason this happens is because `.page-inside` is the first child of the parent container `.page` which doesn't have any content in the normal flow before the `.page-inside` div. Therefore, giving `margin: 30px auto` to `.page-inside` is essentially the same as giving it to `.page` as they are "at the same starting point" in the document.

On the other hand, [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) creates space within an element. If you want to push the main content within `.page-inside` down 30px just use padding like `padding: 30px 0`. This would create 30px of top and bottom "space" within the `.page-inside` element and 0px of left and right space.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:rgb(31, 31, 31);
}

.page-inside {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 30px 0;
    max-width: 95ch;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*margin: 30px auto;*/
}

.row-apps {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row-apps-item {
    color: rgb(57, 57, 207);
    width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

nav {
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 90ch;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 0 .75rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <span>Aplikasi</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>ID</li>
        <li>EN</li>
        <li>Sulaiman</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="page-inside">
            <div class="row-apps">
                <div class="row-apps-item">
                    <img src="02.jpg" class="row-apps-img">
                    Kurikulum
                </div>
                <div class="row-apps-item">
                    <img src="03.jpg" class="row-apps-img">
                    Status Mahasiswa

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice explanation. If I add a random div above `.page-inside`, the margin works as expected. From another post pointed by Paul above, adding `padding-top:1px; margin-top:-1px;` to `.page` solves this also. Thanks