# Simple React component causes irregular margin issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have 3 components: (1) App, (2) Main and (3) Card. The Main component is in the App Component. The Card component is in the Main Component. Here's a runnable example of it:

```js
// Card.js
function Card(props) {
    return <div className="card">
        {props.children}
    </div>
}

// Main.js
/*export*/ function Main() {
    return <div className="main">
        <Card></Card>
    </div>
}

// App.js
function App() {
  return <div>
    <Main></Main>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
/* index.css*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Card.css */
.card {
    background: darkslategrey;
    margin: 20% auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Main.css */
.main {
    background: blanchedalmond;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Index.js has -> App has -> Main. Main has -> Card.

My App Component has no styles.
My Main Component has a few lines which includes colors, height and width.
My Card Component has a few styles - border-radius, color, margin and so on.
Simple styles.

The problem is, everything works fine until I add margin to my Card. Whenever I add margin-top to the Card, the 'root' Component moves down, leaving a chunck of white space on top. I just want my Card to move down.

---

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

App.js

```
function App() {
  return <div>
    <Main></Main>
  </div>
}
```

App.css

```
empty...
```

---

Main.js

```
export function Main() {
    return <div className="main">
        <Card></Card>
    </div>
}
```

Main.css

```
.main {
    background: blanchedalmond;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

---

Card.js

```
function Card(props) {
    return <div className="card">
        {props.children}
    </div>
}
```

Card.css

```
.card {
    background: darkslategrey;
    margin: 20% auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 600px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Output is this:
[image]

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are correct, posted with a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar - I was *fairly* sure, but... :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening due to the [margin-collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).
To fix it, you can set `display: flow-root` on the main div. Learn about [flow-root](https://caniuse.com/flow-root)

**Issue reproduce** :

```css
.card {
  background: grey;
  margin: 20% auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.main {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="card">
      sdasd
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

`Issue Fix` with `display: flow-root`

```css
.card {
  background: grey;
  margin: 20% auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.main {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flow-root
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="card">
      sdasd
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

***`PS`***: `display: flow-root` is not supported on `IE 11 or lower`, if you want to support `IE`, then you can add a transparent border to the main div like `border: 1px solid transparent;` instead of `display: flow-root`

Comment: Isn't there a good dupetarget for this? (I'm not that active in the CSS tag, but if even I've heard of it...) Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element).

Comment: @Tushar that worked! Thannks ;)

Comment: \yes my bad, should have searched, but I will keep my answer as is, @Haseeb if it helped, can you please accept?

Comment: @Tushar it did fix the problem. Thanks again. Accepted.

Comment: oh I cant see it accepted thats why I have asked :)

Comment: @Tushar haha my bad. Apologies. Done.

Answer (score 0):

margin: 20% auto; in the .card is causing the issue, try using padding.