# Why does margin on child of container creates space between html and body?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have this simple html/css-code:

```html
<html>
<body style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="container" style="height: 100vh; min-height: 100vh; background-color: purple;;">
        <div class="child" style="height: 20px; background-color: palegoldenrod; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought the `padding-top` applied to the `.child` element would push it down 10px from the top of the `.container`-div (which is as high as the viewport).

But instead it leads to the `.container` being pushed down (actually the entire body is being pushed down) by these 10px, given that I never applied a margin to the `body` nor the `.container`.

Probably it is very simple, but I just was just a little surprised...

Here is a codepen with that code: https://codepen.io/robinkohrs/pen/BaGabyp

Comment: Generally, padding is easier to use than margin. In your case you want to have padding-top on the parent (.container) not the child (.child).

Comment: A better Question/Answer than what is linked in the Duplicate mention. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element . Can be solved by `overflow: auto;` on parent if height is fixed, or `overflow: hidden;` if not.